# why there is always have a Segmentation fault (core dumped) for my x86 code

Tags: x86

I am a total freshman of x86, and I have a problem when doing the lab. I am trying to finish the code of binary search, but is always shows the error, IDK why

```
section .text

global binsearch

binsearch:
    cmp rdi, rsi
    jg exit_fail
    cmp rdi, 0
    jl exit_fail

    mov r9, 0
    mov r8, rsi
    sub r8, rdi

    shr r8, 3

loop:
    mov r10, r8
    sub r10, r9

    shr r10, 1

    add r10, r9

    mov r11, r10

    shl r11, 3

    add r11, rdi

    mov r11, qword[r11]
    cmp r11, rdx
    jg too_big
    jl too_small
    jmp success

too_big:
    sub r10, 1
    mov r8, r10
    jmp loop

too_small:
    add r10, 1
    mov r9, r10
    jmp loop

exit_fail:
    mov rax, 0
    syscall

success:
    mov rax, r11
    syscall
```

rdi is low, rsi is high and rdx is the number we wish to found

Comment: Run your code in https://x64dbg.com/ and it will show you where exactly the segfault happens.

Comment: @vitsoft: I was going to say this is using Linux system calls directly so a Windows debugger is unlikely to help.  But `rax=0` / `syscall` is `read()` on Linux; `_exit` is RAX=60 with the exit status in EDI.  (So probably that's the bug and this is supposed to be for something other than Windows, since I think other mainstream OSes also use a call number in RAX. And the first instruction looking at RDI and RSI for incoming args also looks like x86-64 SysV, not Windows x64.)